# phpMyAdmin User's edit button

Tags: phpmyadmin

In my phpmyadmin I don't see edit button for users to edit their permissions.

Thanks,

[GUI Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF4KL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had run this command with option GRANT in the end and reboot.

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'rootaccess'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Thanks

Comment: So you didn't see the edit button because the user didn't have proper permissions to edit user privileges. Once you gave that privilege to your user, you were able to see the edit button. Glad you solved this.